# Adding space to items in a wx.Radiobox

Tags: wxpython

I have created a wx.RadioBox control with 8 radiobuttons. I want to add some space between each of these buttons so that they dont look cluttered. Can you please tell me how to do it?

My code is somewhat like this:

```
freqList = ['12 MHz','12.288 MHz','13 MHz','15.36 MHz','19.2 MHz','24 MHz','26 MHz' ,'30 MHz']
radiobox = wx.RadioBox(panel, -1, "Clock Frequencies", (100, 100), wx.DefaultSize,freqList, 1, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way. You may have to use just regular wx.RadioButtons. Feel free to ask on the wxPython mailing list though.